# Mutt: define macro for a specific folder

Tags: mutt

I'd like the following configuration for my mutt.

If the email is in the `foo` folder in mutt, then the `s` key in the attachment view should save the attachment to the `~/bar` directory.

In any other mailbox, the `s` key should be mapped to the normal `<save-entry>` command in the attachment view.

I tried to use a `folder-hook` to map a new macro like this:

```
folder-hook foo "macro attach s <save-entry><kill-line>~/bar/<enter>"
```

But, this command does not unset the macro as soon as I move to a different mailbox. How can I accomplish this unsetting of the macro for all other folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `folder-hook`s are always executed in order.

So you must first provide a configuration that matches all folders; then configurations for particular folders.

In your case, first define the default binding for all folders, and then the particular macro for the foo folder:

```
folder-hook . "macro attach s <save-entry>"
folder-hook foo "macro attach s <save-entry><kill-line>~/bar/<enter>"
```

I found the default binding by pressing <kbd>?</kbd> in the attachment menu and searching for `s`.

This is mentioned in mutt documentation for `folder-hook`:

> ...is not restored to its previous value when reading a different
>   mailbox. To specify a default command, use the pattern “.” before
>   other folder-hooks adjusting a value on a per-folder basis because
>   folder-hooks are evaluated in the order given in the configuration
>   file.

Comment: You're right. I should RTFM more clearly. I had missed out on the `.` representing all folders and was looking for a regex like expression to get the things done.

Comment: `.` is actually a regex; it matches any single character (which all folder names have). I use `.` a lot for un-limiting message list views (`L . <enter>`).